# Why takes the USB device detection of Windows so long?

Tags: windows, usb

Why does Windows need several seconds to recognize the mouse I just plugged in? On MacOS this happens almost instantaneously.

Comment: To get a useful answer, it might be good to retag your question with a specific Windows version.

Answer (score 3):

If its Windows 7, the time taken is incredibly long, especially if its set to use Windows update to scan for drivers on /every/ connect. That plus my flaky, flaky and slow Internet connection which resulted in timeouts means it took forever to detect. Asked Windows not to look at Windows update, and it was much better.

Answer (score 1):

If this is happening just after the boot, then this is normal behavior for Windows starting up with a non-minimal configuration.

The boot process continues even after the desktop is displayed, the disk keeps on churning and processes are queued waiting for Internet access. This slowing down effect is augmented if any antivirus product is installed and its checks slows-down the starting up of applications.

This is something one has to live-with on Windows. Be thankful that it only takes several seconds and not several minutes (like my own over-charged computer).

Answer (score 1):

Windows and pretty much any other OS have completely different structure.It is possible that Unix based OSes(any operating system these days except Windows) can make a safe assumption about the hardware that Windows can't.Leading to Windows "asking" that piece of hardware if it's true or not and then proceeding based on the info provided by the device.What I explained up here is called "handshaking" but I omitted a lot of actual reasons why is handshaking necessary.

Simple answer:Unix based operating systems have a lot more efficient handshaking routines.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: The question is misleading. The delay happens only if the USB device is plugged to a system FIRST time. When the systems sees previously unknown device PID/VID, it must update registry, and search entire system for proper INF file and driver, then "register" them all. After the first time the connection takes a fraction of a second.

Answer (score 0):

Is the hardware comparable?  If your Windows box is not the same as your Mac you would expect different response times.  On my own Windows systems, it takes less than a second to recognize my mice.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a series of stuff:

-Memory; if you run a lot of programs; it takes time; if you don't ; it doesn't take (much) time

-USB Ports: If you have USB 1.0; yes it might run slowly; 2.0 is better.

-Your Windows version; is sometimes the problem.

-we're talking about Windows. (I think you'll understand what i mean)

Answer (score 0):

On my windows system here, I just plugged in a regular £2.99 mouse, it started working instantly. Unplugged my G5, rebooted, and plugged it back in. About half a second (I guess mostly for setpoint to initialise).

At school? Takes 30 seconds on *boot* before peripherals start functioning, 20 if you plug them in after-the-fact. I think it's configuration error, most likely.